# Verification by direct substitution using matrices of ODE

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, substitution

I have this matrix:
$$
    \overline X=\begin{pmatrix}
    c_1e^{-2t} +2c_2e^{5t} \\
    -3c_1e^{-2t}+c_2e^{5t}  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
I want to verify that the above is a soltuion to

$$
    \overline X'=\begin{pmatrix}
    4 & 2 \\
    3 & -1  \\
    \end{pmatrix} \overline X
$$

**by direct substitution:**

However, I don't understand this format and can't figure out what to do. My first instinct is to take the derivative of the first matrix and substitute it into the second one, but I do not think that will work.

Any help would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll do the substitution for you:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    -2c_1e^{-2t} +10c_2e^{5t} \\
    6c_1e^{-2t}+ 5c_2e^{5t} 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 4 & 2 \\
 3 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
    c_1e^{-2t} +2c_2e^{5t} \\
    -3c_1e^{-2t}+c_2e^{5t}  \\
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now you should see the format and be able to check the answer.